# WYSIWYG text editor won't work on my website

Tags: php, html, hosting

I have a website, a company profile website and it has articles and events in it. it was working so fine before this problem shows up.

lately this website is somehow won't work like it used to when i updating or adding new articles in admin panel page, it always sent me back to the website's home page after i clicked submit, until i felt very weird when i tried in localhost and it work perfectly fine.

after all 3 weeks, finally i know the main problem. The problem was my textarea which are using html text type or WYSIWYG  text editor named **ckeditor**.

the question is, i already made this website working for past 2 years with this ckeditor, and somehow this ckeditor won't work like it used to. What's happening? my friends telling me it's because the host and i can't editing the php.ini and i should work with vps rather than with cpanel. is it true? if it is true, any solution for this?

i'm sorry i'm not asking about the code, but it just asking about the text editor, maybe u guys can suggest me something.

btw, i tried using **tinyMCE** too and still have no luck in it.

Comment: Post the source code.  We aren't mind readers here

Comment: @Akintunde what kind of code do u want? i already told my problem and question up there, and it's quite clear. i have trouble using ckeditor or tinyMCE in my website, and it works just fine in my local host. So u tell me which code u wanted? ckeditor javascript, jquery, or so, u can find it in their own link. I know u r doing stackoverflow for 8 months or maybe more with different id, but please don't be so mean and thought so arrogant u donkey, i don't mind to have a downvote from u for ur stupidity comment.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create, edit or delete your php.ini from the cPanel. The php.ini is specific to each folder. Your php version might be out of date. Use [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) to view errors on the webpage. If you are still having troubles, your host should be able to fix any php.ini files for you.

[image]

Comment: m8, can i ask u something? so i'm using php v 5.5 in both my website and my localhost, and i know it's an old version of php, does it to be the problem ?

Comment: @riverrhun: It's best to use at least a supported version with security patches. Currently 5.6. You should migrate to 7+ if you can. [link]http://php.net/supported-versions.php